# Type on python script on the Unix command line (without a .py file)

Tags: unix, python

Working with python 2.7, I want to do this:

```
$> python "import Tkinter; Tkinter.tk(); etc... "
```

but python doesn't seem to accept script this way. I don't want to create a .py file.

Is there a way to give python commands directly on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run:

```
python -c "…"
```

The `-c` argument tells the python interpreter to run the argument value as commands.

```
$ python -c "print 'foo'; print 'bar'"
foo
bar
```

Comment: Sure! Don't forget that you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark next to it.